# ImageTools AnimatedImage not releasing memory

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a WindowsPhone 7.8 application, that needs to display animated GIFs as well as images that are supported directly by Silverlight. Therefor we created a custom user control `public sealed partial class ExtendedImageControl : UserControl, IDisposable`, which has a DependancyProperty called ImageSource. This property is bound to a URL. The code behind will then either insert a regular Image control into the LayoutRoot, or a AnimatedImage. However, the AnimatedImage will not release its memory when it gets out of view or the containing page is closed.

The loading logic is the following:

```
ExtendedImage loadedImage = (ExtendedImage)await Utils.Caching.Image.LoadCachedImageFromUrlAsync<ExtendedImage>(loadedLocation);

                        if (ImageSource == loadedLocation)
                        {
                            AnimatedImage image = new AnimatedImage();
                            image.Stretch = stretch;
                            image.Source = loadedImage;
                            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);
                            CurrentImageMode = ExtendedImageMode.AnimatedImage;
                            loadedImage = null;
#if DEBUG
                            App.logger.log("Loaded {0} as animated image", loadedLocation);
#endif
                            imageDisplay = image;
                            raiseImageUpdated();
                        }
```

Ultimately, the image is loaded with

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        ExtendedImage image = new ExtendedImage();
        using (Stream source = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(location))
        {

            if (location.ToString().EndsWith("gif", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                image.SetSource(source);

                TaskCompletionSource<ExtendedImage> imageLoaded = new TaskCompletionSource<ExtendedImage>();

                EventHandler loadingCompleteHandler = new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
                {
                    imageLoaded.SetResult(image);
                });

                EventHandler<UnhandledExceptionEventArgs> loadingFailedHandler = new EventHandler<UnhandledExceptionEventArgs>((sender, e) =>
                {
                    imageLoaded.SetResult(image);
#if DEBUG
                    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#endif
                });



                image.LoadingCompleted += loadingCompleteHandler;
                image.LoadingFailed += loadingFailedHandler;

                image = await imageLoaded.Task;

                //Remove handlers, otherwise the object might be kept in the memory
                image.LoadingCompleted -= loadingCompleteHandler;
                image.LoadingFailed -= loadingFailedHandler;
            }
            else
            {
                //... load with native Silverlight methods
            }
        }

        return image;
```

We noticed the memory problem very early on, so the control implements the IDisposable interface with

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        unloadImage();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void unloadImage()
    {
        SmartDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (imageDisplay != null)
            {
                if (imageDisplay is AnimatedImage)
                {
                    if ((imageDisplay as AnimatedImage).Source != null & (imageDisplay as AnimatedImage).Source.Frames != null)
                        (imageDisplay as AnimatedImage).Source.Frames.Clear();

                    (imageDisplay as AnimatedImage).Stop();

                    (imageDisplay as AnimatedImage).Source = null;
                }
                else if (imageDisplay is Image && ((Image)imageDisplay).Source != GIFplaceholder)
                {
                    (imageDisplay as Image).Source = null;
                }

                imageDisplay = null;
            }
        });
    }
```

However, the Dispose method is never called on the image.

What can I do to find out why this object isn't picked up by the GC? I'm not registering any eventhandlers so as far as I understand, it should be collected when the Application page is navigated away from. I tried adding a destructor as well, however this one is not called as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is...

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I wanted to know how I can find out what's preventing my AnimatedImage control from being garbage collected. As far as I can tell, I'm not registering any eventhandlers, and I don't have any references to the control outside of the page. So shouldn't it be garbage collected when I navigate back from the containing page?

Comment: What makes you think it is not garbage collected? If it's about your `Dispose` method that isn't called, I think you're misunderstanding things. The Dispose method isn't called by the garbage collector, it's the other way around: it's meant to be directly called by the developper to clean up resources that won't be taken care of by the GC.  Anyway, about the leak, make sure you call the `Stop` method of the AnimatedImage when leaving the page, to stop the timer used internally.

Comment: I did some profiling and when I navigate away from the page, the memory usage stays very high. The memory is almost solely used by the ExtendedImgae/AnimatedImage. I tried calling the ExtendedImage.Dispose method (which also stops the timer - see above), but I'm still loosing memory when I open up a new page containing the user control and navigate back followed by navigating again to the page with the usercontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory leak is not in ImageTools but is actually a bug in the Silverlight Runtime:

> Memory Leak when you Dynamically add and remove Images
>
> Workaround: When dynamically adding or removing BitmapImages from an
>   application (a.k.a. adding/removing from the tree), you should set
>   Image.Source = null before removing the Image element from the tree.
>   This will make the BitmapImage eligible for garbage collection. Bug
>   Status: Active bug. *

References:

[Silverlight: How to unload (dispose) an image from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433434/silverlight-how-to-unload-dispose-an-image-from-memory)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight_sdk/2008/10/28/silverlight-bugs-and-workarounds/

One can quickly verify that setting each ExtendedImage to Nothing before back navigating away from the XAML page can result in dramatic reduction in application memory use.

I add the following to my RootFrame_Navigating event in App.xaml to help track these leaks:

```
Dim applicationCurrentMemoryUsage As Long = Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage")
Dim applicationPeakMemoryUsage As Long = Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage")
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() & " Current : " & applicationCurrentMemoryUsage & "  Peak : " & applicationPeakMemoryUsage)
```

Answer (score 0):

> it should be collected when the Application page is navigated away from

Put code in the navigation process to actually call dispose and unlink the image from the page. Whatever is holding the image may not be being disposed, hence the image never gets disposed. Do it by hand and then see if the same is occurring.

---

The OP reported that something about animated image is still a concern. Make sure that there are no subscriptions `pinning` the image to memory. All subscriptions must be removed with a `-=` de-subscription process. Otherwise even though there are no references to the object, any subscription *pins* it to memory keeping it alive.

Comment: The control itself is not disposable. I'm currently working around by setting the image source to zero and removing all event handlers. However, I'm still losing memory, and profiling shows that the AnimatedImage controls are still "alive".

Answer (score -1):

If anyone stumbles across this...

See [here](https://imagetools.codeplex.com/workitem/10396) for solution.

Short answer: call Stop() on AnimatedImage before navigating away.

EDIT: I have updated the library to automatically Stop animation when the control is removed from the page. Download and build the latest version of the source.